# How do I repeat the first character of words in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

Using Ruby 2.4.  I have a string with letters and spaces.  For example,

```
"abc def"
```

How do I change the string such that I duplicate the first character of each word?  That is, the above would become:

```
"aabc ddef"
```

because "a" and "d" are the start of the words in the above string.  By word, I mean any sequence of characters separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just split the string by each space, and multiply the first character the number of times you need, then append, or concatenate the "initial" word:

```
p "abc def".split.map { |word| "#{word[0] * 10}#{word}" }.join(' ')
```

Comment: gsub could work with the same block, `"abc def".gsub(/\w+/) { ... }`.

Comment: If you use `gsub` you might as well go all in :-P

Comment: `word[0] * 10 + word` would also be acceptable for the mapping.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use gsub to find and double them.

```
"abc def".gsub(/\b\w/, '\0\0')
=> "aabc ddef"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below snippet

```
str = "abc def"
index = 0
new_str = ""

str.split.each do | string |
    string = string[0] + string
    new_str = new_str + string + " "
    index = index + 1
end

puts "New string #{new_str}"
```