# Outputting the values of an array given an array of indexes

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops

Given an array such as `words = ["hello", ", ", "world", "!"]`, I am required to manipulate the elements which are made up of letters, so I will get a string in the end such as `"*hello*, *world*!"`

I have managed to retrieve the indexes from the array which contain letters using `words.map.with_index { |element, index| index if element[[/a-zA-Z+/]] == element }.compact`, which are `[0, 2]`.

How could I use these indexes in a function, such that I could manipulate the words?

Comment: Unclear. Why do you collect the indices instead of directly collecting or modifying the words?

Comment: I think you are over thinking the problem a bit. Since the desired end result is a string it would make the most sense in this case to convert it to a `String` and then manipulate it using the methods `String` provides `words.join.gsub(/\w+/) {|m| "*#{m}*"}`

Comment: @engineersmnky Or slightly shorter using a variation of an answer Stefan provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47822701/5101493) `words.join.gsub(/\w+/,'*\0*')`.

Comment: @SagarPandya Nah, `words.join.gsub(/\b/, '*')`.

Comment: @SagarPandya What does the `'*\0*'` do exactly?

Comment: @AshNaz87 `\0` represents the matched sequence. So `gsub` first matches `hello`, so `\0` equals `hello`.  Then replaces `hello` with `*\0*` which is the same as `*hello*`. Then again for the next match `world`. It's like the `m` in engineersmnky's solution above.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I would have given you the tick to accept your answer, but it wasn't there. Still, I appreciate everyone's input. Thanks all!

Comment: @AshNaz87 So you don't have numbers, or you do want to put asterisks around them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need indexes for this. If you want to be able to put apply arbitrary logic to each array element, use `map` without indexes:

```
words.map{|w| w.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,'*\0*')}.join
```

As others have pointed out, for the example you have given, you don't need to process the array at all, just join it into a string first. For example:

```
words.join.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,'*\0*')
```

Comment: Well, I'd say it fails for example for `["hello", ", ", "42", "!"]` which it turns into `"*hello*, *42*!"`, surrounding the *number* with asterisks. (That's one reason I didn't post it as answer myself but just as comment-reply to the previous comments)

Comment: Good point, I've changed it to use OP's regex. Hey, digits are word characters according to regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regexp,  that would make your job easy. You can manipulate the elements after fetching it in an array

```
words = ["hello", ", ", "world", "!"]
array = []
words.each do |a|
  array << a if /\w/.match(a)
end

puts array

hello
world
```

Comment: I think OP wants `"*hello*, *world*!"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words.reject { |word| word.match?(/\p{^L}/) }.
      map { |word| "*%s*" % word }.
      join(', ')
  #=> "*hello*, *world*"
```